# Why doesn't C# support implicit interface conversion for interface implementation members?

Tags: c#, interface

Consider this:

```
   interface IA
    {

    }

    public class A : IA
    {

    }

    interface IB
    {
         IA PropertyA { get; set; }
    }


    class B : IB
    {
        public A PropertyA { get; set; }
    }
```

This isn't allowed, since class B doesn't implement propertyA of type IA. IE PropertyA in the class is of type A in the class not IA.

But this seems a great shame since A supports IA it should be trivial for compiler/language to support this and implicitly handle the conversion.

This design pattern could be really useful if it were allowed as one could automatically generate an interface model of a class abstracting it's implementation. Does anyone know any workaround?

Comment: Default Implementations are a proposed feature of C# 8.  It's not in the language yet, so while it is logical, consistent interface behavior is best practice.

Comment: @AdamHess It _seems_ logical, but can blow up. See my example below.

Comment: @DStanley good point, I forgot about generics.

Comment: I see. Your example is only a problem if a setter is declared in the interface, I would actually only need get access in my interface to implement my design pattern so this wouldn't be a problem . I can't use generics since my SQL class mapper doesn't support them. I'll look into c# 8!

Comment: So this wouldn't break at run-time (if it compiled):        interface ITest
        {
             
        }

        public class Test : ITest
        {

        }

        interface ITest2
        {
            ITest A { get; }
        }


        class Test2 : ITest2
        {
            public Test A { get; set; }
        }

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because then this would compile, but would blow up at runtime:

```
public class A2 : IA
{
}

B b = new B();  // fine
IB ib = b;      // fine
ib.PropertyA = new A2();  // blows up at runtime since B can only hold A objects in PropertyA
```

> Does anyone know any workaround?

Generics:

```
interface IB<T> where T:IA
{
     T PropertyA { get; set; }
}

class B : IB<A>
{
    public A PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this workaround doesn't work in practice as reality A and B actually reference each other. (I didn't show this in my example)

Comment: Really would like to do is this (which doesn't break at run-time) :     interface IA
    {
        IB PropertyB { get; }
    }

    public class A : IA
    {
        public B PropertyA { get; set; }
    }

    interface IB
    {
         IA PropertyA { get;  }
    }


    class B : IB
    {
        public A PropertyA { get; set; }
    }

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/49